# Prevent Gradle Zip task from downloading dependencies before task execution

Tags: gradle

I have a simple gradle task that zips a maven jar (for an example). How do you get this task to not download the jar until the task is executed?

```
apply plugin:'base'
repositories { mavenCentral() }

configurations.create 'myDep'
dependencies {
   myDep 'commons-io:commons-io:1.0'
}
task zip(type:Zip) {
   from { configurations.myDep.collect { zipTree(it) } }
}
```

If I run 'gradle tasks', it will download the jar unexpectedly:

```
$ gradle tasks
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.0/commons-io-1.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.0/commons-io-1.0.jar
:tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `gradle tasks` is a special case, as it needs to evaluate inputs of *all* tasks to determine (and display) their task dependencies. In general, the `zip` task's inputs will only be evaluated (and therefore the Jar downloaded) once Gradle has decided to execute the `zip` task. This will happen during building of the task execution graph (again to determine task dependencies), that is *before* any task is executed (but only *if* Gradle has decided to execute `zip`).

If you absolutely must prevent downloading of the Jar in case of `gradle tasks`, you can defer configuring the `from` until `zip.doFirst {}`, but this is not a general solution and can cause other problems (up-to-date checks not working correctly, task dependencies not being inferred automatically).

Comment: Ok, I see now. This is unfortunate because 'gradle tasks' is probably the first command most users run. I have some dependencies that are >200MB. I don't think gradle should have to download dependencies to print the task listing.

Comment: It doesn't typically, but it does in this particular case, and only for the dependencies on `myDep`. Perhaps `zipTree` could accept an `Iterable<File>`. Then you wouldn't have to use `collect`, the configuration wouldn't get resolved at that stage, and the problem would go away.